# How to change android logcat color in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, logcat

I use eclipse luna and general>appearance is dark and color theme(seperate plugin) is sunburst.but logcat's color is very pale.
I tried to change Android>logcat>change and I changed black to white and applied.but When I reopen going black again and it does not change anything on the screen.
screenshot:
[image: screenshot link]

> How do I make logcat's text more visible?

Answer (score 3):

Go to

> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> LogCat -> Colors

There you can change the text colors for the different message types, but you can't change the background color, to do that you have to play around with a mix of Eclipse themes and Windows themes.

Answer (score 2):

Log cat in dark theme appears a bit dull and hard to read.
I changed font style to bold from Window -> Preferences -> Android -> LogCat -> Colors
And also made colors a bit bright.
So now its easily readable[image]

Comment: Haha definitely hacky way but dude, it works just fine :) Thanks!